# Whether there is a function to create assoc array from other array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with two values, something like `((id, value), (id, value), (id, value))` and i need to do the array like `id => value` so i wondering is there some functions in php for this kind of job or i need to write my own. Just don't want to reinvent the wheel....

**UPDATE**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["site_id"]=>
    string(3) "12"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(19) "2014-01-09 08:48:40"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["site_id"]=>
    string(3) "13"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-07 14:27:57"
  }
}
```

Comment: `array_map` + `array_combine`

Comment: The most straight forward way is a loop here. There's no function which does *exactly* that, and combining several functions is not going to be as efficient as a simple loop.

Answer (score 6):

Some HOFs in php, just for fun:

```
$data = array(
    array('foo', 'bar'),
    array('baz', '42'),
);

$ithIx = function($ix) {
    return function($item) use($ix) {
        return $item[$ix];
    };
};

$combined = array_combine(
    array_map($ithIx(0), $data),
    array_map($ithIx(1), $data)
);

var_dump($combined);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/jIsgpL

For the ones who cannot see beauty in functional style - here is some boring `foreach`:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $combined[$val[0]] = $val[1];
}
```

Comment: Nice showcase of functional composition. Not quite the most practical solution though I'd say... ;)

Comment: @deceze: that's why just for fun :-)

Comment: @Kirix: I'm surprised a person who can count loops in this code cannot write a trivial `foreach` 2 lines code

Comment: @zerkms i'm asked not for loops count, but for already built in function. P.S. minus is not my

Comment: @Kirix: and I provided a solution that is based on a built in functions (check your answer - I don't see anything about number of iterations (either explicit or implicit) to be used in an accepted solution). Do you honestly expect to see something like `aMagicFunctionThatAcceptsMyVeryOwnFormatAndReturnsWhatINeed()`?

Comment: @zerkms Well, yes, it's php

Comment: @Kirix: do you know any built-in function that would do the same in python, java, js, c# or whatever mainstream language you know better?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (semi-boring):

```
$a = array(
    array(1, 'Hello'),
    array(2, 'World')
);

$a = array_combine(array_column($a, 0), array_column($a, 1));
```

(if PHP < 5.5)

```
function array_column($array, $column)
{
    return array_map(function($e) use ($column) {return $e[$column];}, $array);
}
```